# No Launcher Activity Found - Android

Tags: android, eclipse

No matter what I try I still get this error:

```
[2014-12-07 19:29:19 - ---] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-12-07 19:29:19 - ---] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

I believe I have set up the manifest correctly but Eclipse still gives me errors

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Looks correct.. in eclipse try: Project -> Clean -> All -> Clean!

Comment: You have an activity called Splash, right ? This may be a silly qusetion, but better be sure than sorry lol

Comment: Also try using full package name for launcher activity (e.g., com.youdomain.yourapp.Splash).

Answer (score 0):

Found out is was just Eclipse. The project works when I export it and run it on my device.